# How to write the following MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have the following `foobar` collection:

```
{
  "foobar": [
    {
      "_id": "abc",
      "history": [
        {
          "type": "foo",
          "timestamp": 123456789.0
        },
        {
          "type": "bar",
          "timestamp": 123456789.0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "dfg",
      "history": [
        {
          "type": "baz",
          "timestamp": 123456789.0
        },
        {
          "type": "bar",
          "timestamp": 123456789.0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "hij",
      "history": [
        {
          "type": "foo",
          "timestamp": 123456789.0
        },
        {
          "type": "bar",
          "timestamp": 123456789.0
        },
        {
          "type": "foo",
          "timestamp": 123456789.0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I query (`$gte`/`$lte`) the `foobar` items based on the `timestamp` prop inside their `history` items, but using the `timestamp` from the item where `type: "foo"`?

If there is no subdocuments with `type` equals to `foo`, the entire document is filtered out, if there is more than one subdocument with `type` equals to `foo` then it could match anyone.

Comment: What should happen in case there's no type: foo. Should that document be filtered out ? And what if there's more than one foo ? Could you edit your post and add expected output for your document ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation:

```
var threshold = 123456788;
db.foobar.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            foobar: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$foobar",
                    as: "doc",
                    cond: {
                        $let: {
                            vars: { 
                                foo: {
                                    $arrayElemAt: [
                                        {
                                            $filter: {
                                                input: "$$doc.history",
                                                as: "history",
                                                cond: {
                                                    $eq: [ "$$history.type", "foo" ]
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        0]
                                }
                            },
                            in: {
                                $gt: [ "$$foo.timestamp", threshold ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) can be used to overwrite existing field (`foobar`). To filter out all subdocuments not matching your condition you can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) (the outer one). For each `foobar` document you can use [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) to define temporary variable `foo`. You need inner `$filter` to get all `history` elements where `type` is `foo` and then [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/?searchProperty=current&query=%24addFields) to get first one. Then you just need `$gt` or `$lt` to apply your comparison.

For those subdocuments where there's no `foo` there will be `undefined` returned which will be then filtered out on `$gt` stage.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it out.